# The indexing process is hang up?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am loading table with 41 millions of files from sql dump to table.
PostgreSQL Server 14.3 is setuped with best practice from google (workmem, jobs etc).

Table have a lot of index. After loading of dump I have seen in cmd next:

```
...
INSERT 0 250
INSERT 0 250
INSERT 0 141
  setval
----------
 41349316

ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
```

And by output it continue to do something. Process in CMD is not finished. No new line just as I had show.

I checked current activity with:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'dbname';
```

It show `idle` for column `state` google says that it show last command that was run in session. I checked after few hours and nothing is changed.

`pg_stat_progress_create_index` do not show nothing.

So I do not know what to do. Could indexing process is hanged? Or all fine and I should to wait? If yes what it's doing now? What I can\should to do?

**UPD** from next morning: Today I rechecked all

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_progress_create_index;
```

is still do not show nothing.

Console window did two new prints:

```
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
```

I again checked:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'dbname';
```

it show that active process is:

```
CREATE INDEX index_insert_status ON public.xml_files USING btree (insert_status);
```

But why `pg_stat_progress_create_index` do not show nothing??

Comment: I mean that process is still active. Not terminated, not return back to cmd.

Comment: SQL does not (in general anyway) produce output until it is complete. You should probably wait. You may want to investigate if anything is locking to table you are working on and your process is waiting for the lock(s) to clear.

Comment: @Belayer but why `pg_stat_progress_create_index` do not show index creation? Should it show it always or it show only some steps?

Comment: It could be in the `alter table`. Check your server log.

Comment: Altering (depending on what you're doing) and indexing a table with 41 million rows can take quite some time, especially on a slow disk. You could try altering the table *before* inserting, that could speed up the `alter table` considerably, and [building the indexes concurrently](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY). Or just wait.

Comment: I sometimes find that the windowing system "forgets" to update the terminal window when it has been under heavy load.  So the command looks like it is still running, even though it has finished.  Putting the terminal window in focus and hitting <enter> will then "wake it up" to display the last line of output, and display the shell prompt.  If it were in this situation, I would not expect to see any corresponding line in pg_stat_activity, but if it were in any other situation I can think of, I would expect a line other than 'idle'.